# PHP Switch statement: is this correct?

Tags: php, syntax

I've taken a look at the documentation for switch on php.net and as best as I can tell it checks a equality comparison between the variable in the switch and the case. However, the following code seems to work properly for all possible values (int, null, array, other):

```
$x = array('one','two');

switch ($x) {
   case null:
      echo "is null!";
      break;
   case is_int($x):
       echo "is int";
       break;
   case is_array($x):
      echo "is array!";
      break;
   default:
      echo "something else!";
      break;
}
```

From what I read, it should be comparing is_int($a) [true] to $x [an array, which evaluates to true] and giving an incorrect result.

My question is ... why is this actually working?

### EDIT: sorry I had not copied it quite correctly as I'd been messing about with it. Its now in its working form

Comment: Is it working? It gives me errors (because `$a` is undefined) and reports "something else".

Comment: Erm, I don't quite follow - what is `$x` in your example? Or did you just mix up `$a` and `$x`? One probable answer is that you would do well to understand what `switch (true) { case is_foo($x): ... }` does, and why it is correct - which might shed light on why your code works. As you said, a non-empty array evaluates to true... Why do you think it is "giving an incorrect result"?

Comment: -1 There's a typo in your code, as @Amadan correctly pointed out. Should be is_array($x) instead of instead of is_array($a)

Comment: Why would you possibly downvote for a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_int($x)` does not evaluate to true if x is an array.  This works because `array('one', 'two')` is considered true, and `is_array()` will evaluate to true.  This means it does not match `null` or `is_int($x)` (the latter comes out to false).  If it's an int, then the opposite is true and `is_array($x)` becomes false.  If `$x` is `null`, it evaluates to `false`, as does `null` in the switch.  The `null` case will be executed for any circumstance where `$x` is false (try it with `false`, `array()`, `0`, and others).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct, but the code is not doing what you think it does.

If you have an expression as switch case

```
 case is_array($othervar):
```

Then this expression will (1) not take the actual switch variable into account and (2) be evaluated before the switch runs. In essence the `case` will then become

```
 case TRUE:
```

And this is the value that is then compared against the `switch ($x)` and which is why it might accidentially work in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior relies on truthy and falsy values:

```
$var = array(1, 2, 3);

// equivalent with if($var){
if($var == true){
  echo 'this will execute';
}
```

Values like `0` and `array()` are falsy values, `1`, `"test"` and `array(1, 2)` are truthy.

If you want to compare the type, you should use `===`, but that is impossible in a switch statement.